# Is it possible to instantiate an interface in java?

Tags: java, oop, interface

I was going through a java tutorial on Spring Retry and there I read about `RetryCallback`, which is an **interface**.

In the same tutorial, I found this chunk of code:

```
retryTemplate.execute(new RetryCallback<Void, RuntimeException>() {
    @Override
    public Void doWithRetry(RetryContext arg0) {
        myService.templateRetryService();
        ...
    }
});
```

The way I see it, an anonymous object of `RetryCallback` is being instantiated. But then we just read **it's an interface**.

Could someone explain what's happening here?

Although not required, but just in case [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-retry)'s a link to the tutorial

Comment: Like you said, it's an anonymous subclass of the interface.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This:

```
new RetryCallback<Void, RuntimeException>() {
    @Override
    public Void doWithRetry(RetryContext arg0) {
        myService.templateRetryService();
        ...
    }
}
```

is an [*anonymous class*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9.5). When this code is run, an object of class `MyContainingClass$1`, which implements `RetryCallback`, instantiated.

When instantiated within an instance method, anonymous classes have an implicit reference to the `MyContainingClass` instance, which is accessed via the syntax `MyContainingClass.this`.

Note that the `1` in the class name is actually `n` where the anonymous class is positioned n<sup>th</sup> relative to all anonymous classes in the containing class.

Answer (score 3):

its just providing a inline implementation for that interface, its not instantiating the interface. its equivalent of creating a new class a that implements RetryCallback, and passing to to execute

Answer (score 0):

The question written in the title of your post:

> *Is it possible to instantiate an interface in java?*

No, it is not possible. From [4.12.6. Types, Classes, and Interfaces in JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se18/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.6) (bold emphasis added by me):

> *Even though a variable or expression may have a compile-time type that is an interface type, **there are no instances of interfaces**. A variable or expression whose type is an interface type can reference any object whose class implements (§8.1.5) that interface.*